# Cpp Access violation reading location when trying to print from array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a program that when a word is inserted into a text document. The definition is outputted to the console. However, whenever I try to output the definition, I get "Acess violation reading location"on line std::cout << Dict[i+1] << std::endl;

Any help with this would be appreciated.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
class Synonym
{
public:
    std::string Dict[14] = {"foo1", "a two o's file", "fooo2,", "a three o's file", "foooo3", "a four o's file", "fooooo4", "a five o's file", "foooooo5", "a six o's file", "fooooooo", "a seven o's file"};
    ~Synonym();
    void checkEqual();
};
```

```
#include "Synonym.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


Synonym::~Synonym()
{

}

void Synonym::checkEqual()
{
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("Synonym.txt");
    std::string x;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Dict); ++i)
    {
        fin >> x;
        if (x == Dict[i])
        {
            std::cout << Dict[i+1] << std::endl;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you're iterating over Dict with i = 0 to 13 (sizeof(Dict)) and then suddenly you try to access i+1... now, what do you think will happen when i = 13?

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: `sizeof(Dict)` will be `14 * sizeof(std::string)`, that's a bit too much